# Google maps v3 Alternative to GLayer in Google maps v2

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having an existing application with

```
var panaramioOverlay = new GLayer("com.panoramio.all");
var wikipediaOverlay = new GLayer("org.wikipedia.en");
var webcamOverlay = new GLayer("com.google.webcams");
```

Is there any alternative way to do in Google Maps v3?